# ZFS broken on Centos 7.8

Tags: centos-7, zfs

I am using ZFSonLinux under CentOS 7, and after a restart, the kernel updated to 7.8. the ZFS modules were not loaded and `modprobe zfs` said the modules were not found. `dkms status` was empty and having attempted to reinstall `zfs` and the `kernel-devel` and `kernel-header` tools, the `dkms` command is no longer even found.

The [zfsonlinux.org](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/wiki/RHEL-and-CentOS) site lists a repo for CentOS 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 8.0 and 8.1.

I know there is a kABI variant that does not need DKMS, though still the installation falls over when the zfs modules are found to not be loaded and be nonexistent.

Where am I at with this..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, it required using the zfsonlinux release for CentOS 7.7, and critically the `zfs-dkms` package. The `epel-release` needed to be reinstalled to allow `yum` to find a compatible `dkms` installation. With this and the zfs-dkms installed, `dkms status` immediately showed that the zfs module was available.

From this point `zfs` and `zpool` commands are working fine.